# Riemann aggerate some last 10 minutes event and alert error. Which use moving-time-window

Tags: clojure, alert, monitoring, riemann

For example, If we want to send the mean data of last 10 minutes alert freezhan if the mean of metric is more than 1000, I express the idea in riemann like this:

```
(streams
  (moving-time-window 
    600 ; 600 sec = 10 min
    (folds/mean
    (where (> metric 1000)
      (email "freezhan@mycompany.com")))))
```

But get some error like this:

> INFO [2016-06-01 18:26:49,002] SIGHUP handler - riemann.pubsub - Sweeping transient subscriptions.
>   ERROR [2016-06-01 18:26:49,069] SIGHUP handler - riemann.bin - Couldn't reload:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: riemann.config$eval2171$stream__2172, compiling:(/etc/riemann/riemann.config:51:38)
>       at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7142)
>       at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)
>       at clojure.lang.RT$3.invoke(RT.java:318)
>       at riemann.config$include.invoke(config.clj:408)
>       at riemann.bin$reload_BANG_.invoke(bin.clj:27)
>       at riemann.bin$handle_signals$fn__11886.invoke(bin.clj:43)
>       at riemann.bin.proxy$java.lang.Object$SignalHandler$d8c00ec7.handle(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Signal$1.run(Signal.java:212)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: riemann.config$eval2171$stream__2172
>       at clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom(RT.java:505)
>       at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:486)
>       at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
>       at clojure.core$filter$fn__4264.invoke(core.clj:2595)
>       at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40)
>       at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49)
>       at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:484)
>       at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
>       at clojure.core$sort.invoke(core.clj:2827)
>       at clojure.core$sort_by.invoke(core.clj:2844)
>       at clojure.core$sort_by.invoke(core.clj:2842)
>       at riemann.folds$sorted_sample_extract.invoke(folds.clj:22)
>       at riemann.folds$median.invoke(folds.clj:169)
>       at riemann.config$eval2171.invoke(riemann.config:58)
>       at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
>       at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
>       ... 8 more

Answer (score 2):

> Don't know how to create ISeq from: riemann.config$eval2171$stream__2172

This indicates some sort of type error, some code expects stuff that implements the `ISeq` protocol, but something else is passed. So lets dig down:

[moving-time-window](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.streams.html#var-moving-time-window):

> Every time a new event arrives within the window, emits a **vector** of events in the window to children.

Vectors don't implement `ISeq`, so this is most likely the problem. Try wrapping the `fold/mean` function with [smap](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.streams.html#var-smap):

```
(streams
  (moving-time-window 
    600 ; 600 sec = 10 min
    (smap folds/mean
    (where (> metric 1000)
      (email "freezhan@mycompany.com")))))
```